# Do people get birth even they are (almost) eligible for Moksha

Tags: moksha

Is it possible for taking birth even the Jeeva is eligible for Moksha?

I'm asking this question for normal human beings, not for the avatar as Krishna, Rama etc.,

If possible, then show an example of such human being, if exists.

Comment: How can one know if other person is eligible for moksha? What is the criteria? We are not the judges for other person's deeds and moksha. It's God who gives moksha.

Comment: "almost" means the soul which yet to cross other side of shore but is so near to cross it but the life of that body ends. So the soul takes another birth to complete!

Comment: How will they get moksha without getting born as a human being? Because scriptures say that usually only from a human birth moksha is possible and also possible only from Bhuloka. So they hv to ..

Comment: Or are you asking in the sense - if person can be granted Moksha as he has full qualifications for it and still can he take another birth?

Comment: @Akshay Kunar S I am asking the one similar to Jada Bharat told by RARA in his comments for the answer.

Comment: Then my previous comment and as iammlind told as an answer should answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already suggested in 1 comment, if a person is "almost" eligible for *Moksha*, then they have to born again.
The birth cycle ends only after the liberation is attained.

This is analogous to the fallen Yogi terminology from Bhagavad Gita.
A fallen Yogi is a person, who fell more or less short of attaining the final destination. Hence gets reborn and starts perseverance from where it was left.

Similar Q&A during Gita:

> BG 6.37 - Arjuna asked, those who possess faith, but wavers mind away from Yoga (state of attaining liberation); **After failing to be perfect in Yoga, what state do they attain?**
>
> BG 6.40 - Blessed lord said, O Partha, neither here nor hereafter, their destruction happens; O dear, **none** of those engaged in such auspicious activity, **goes to downfall**.
> BG 6.43 - There [in the new body] they a**quire the recollection of intellect of the previous body; And thereafter they persevere (put strong efforts) more for perfection**

The examples are trivial. Those who attained Moksha during their birth, were almost perfecting in Yoga till their previous birth:

- Shri RAma
- Shri Krishna
- Drona
- ShishupAla
- Ravana
- Even there is story about Ramakrishna Parmahamsa & Vivekananda taking 1 more birth

All of above, apparently got liberated during their last birth. So they would have fallen short of the perfection till their 2nd last birth.

---

Refer this matching answer:
[What will happen to a youth who wants to enjoy life as well as continuing spiritual efforts?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23770/1049)

Comment: @hanugm There is example of Bharat who became deer and then became Jada Bharat in Srimad Bhagavatam https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5 from chapter 7 onwards

Comment: "they would have fallen short of the perfection till their 2nd last birth"--- Rama & Krishna are incarnations (Adikarikas)...and for Adikarikas rule for moksha is different : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29615/12304

Comment: @iammilind It is odd that you have mentioned Rama and Krishna in that list. Could you quote references that indicate that they were not liberated during their avatara leela and only got liberated at the end of their earthly stint?

Comment: @Ambi, When a person is liberated, he/she doesn't leave any traces in any form. So until an *AvatAra* or a godly figure is in *leela*, he might be a *jeevan-mukta*. But, the liberation happens once they discard earthy body, the mind and senses. Now, refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16314/1049), which quotes the previous births of Shri Krishna. Since the rebirth happened for Shri Krishna, the liberation wouldn't have occurred. I don't have any localised sources of Rama's previous birth(s).

Comment: @iammilind that goes directly in opposition to what Sri Krishna says in the Bhagavad Gita 9.11 and Srimad Bhagavatam 10.14.2. It is a long shot to call Rama and Krishna as taking births or attaining moksha by the normal definition of human birth or their moksha, contrary to what has been explained by the acharyas of the past. And beyond that, there is no evidence that they 'attained moksha', esp. when sampradayic traditions clearly hold that they are the ones giving it. I did read the answer linked, but that is a overly simplistic conclusion, IMHO.

Comment: @Ambi, no it doesn't contradict to anything from Gita. During its discourse, Shri Krishna was in the state of Yoga (viz. connecting to purest form of Brahman or Atma). Hence he used words like "I", "Me" to refer it, but not himself. As per Gita, whatever has beginning, also has end. Lord Krishna & Arjuna assumed various bodies in many of their previous births. Prime among them was Rushi Nara-Narayana. During Mahabharata that consciousness was at its prime, started with birth in a jail, lived the righteous life & discarded body, mind everything at Dwarika. He had a body, & that had to end.

Comment: @iammilind clearly, then, we will have to disagree on that point of Krishna being in connection with some third entity just like we disagree on the nature of Rama and Krishna... either that they had consciousness that was less than perfect intitially (since both are non-different from Narayana) and became perfect over time or that they had material bodies that end like it did for normal humans.

Comment: @iammilind, what ?? you think Rama & Krishna are jeevas that need liberation ? lol

Answer (score 7):

Already User iammilind has quoted from 6th chapter of gita which clearly shows that one has to take birth until he is completely perfect.

One of the names of Lord Krishna or in fact all avatars of Vishnu is Mukunda.

The meaning of Mukunda is 'giver of mukti'.

So there is no question of Krishna/Ram getting liberated. They are never conditioned.

That's why Krishna says:

[Bg 4.9](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=4&field_nsutra_value=9&etsiva=1&choose=1) He who thus know, in their true light, My divine birth and action, having abandoned the body, is not born again, he comes to Me, O Arjuna

[BG 4.14](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/14) There is no work that affects Me; nor do I aspire for the fruits of action. One who understands this truth about Me also does not become entangled in the fruitive reactions of work.

Few examples of human beings who got/going to get liberated:

1)Narada: He was a gandharva upabarhana in one life, then he took birth on earth, then in next life he became Narada

> [SB 7.15.69](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/15/69): Long, long ago, in another mahā-kalpa [millennium of
>   Brahmā], I existed as the Gandharva known as Upabarhaṇa. I was very
>   respected by the other Gandharvas.
>
> [SB 1.6.21](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/6/21): O Narada [the Lord spoke], I regret that during this
>   lifetime you will not be able to see Me anymore. Those who are
>   incomplete in service and who are not completely free from all
>   material taints can hardly see Me.

2)Jada Bharat:

> There is example of Bharat who became deer and then became Jada
>   Bharat in     Srimad Bhagavatam [this chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/7) onwards.

3)King Mucukunda:

> [SB 10.51.63](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/51/63) — O King, in your very next life you will become an
>   excellent     brāhmaṇa, the greatest well-wisher of all creatures, and
>   certainly come to Me     alone.

4)Elephant Gajendra:

> He was king Indradyumna in previous life, the story comes in [8th Canto](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/2)
>   of Bhagavatam.

5)Nalkuvera and Manigriva:

They were gandharvas, cursed to become trees, then again reinstated and got benediction that they would never fall from their consciousness which means, that is going to be their life.

> [SB 10.10.42](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/10/42) — O Nalakūvara and Maṇigrīva, now you may both return
>   home. Since you desire to be always absorbed in My devotional service,
>   your desire to develop love and affection for Me will be fulfilled,
>   and now you will never fall from that platform.

6) King Chitraketu :

Chitraketu became Vrttasura in next life and then became perfect. Story comes from 6th Canto of Bhagavatam.

The examples of Sisupala, Dantavakra can be given, but they were Jaya and Vijaya in Vaikunta who were anyways destined to take 3 births and then liberated.

Comment: It seems in a bid to answer to my answer, you have missed to address the title of the question.

Comment: @iammilind I updated the answer. Anyways the question also mentioned Rama and Krishna in it. My answer is vaishnavite school perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Only Ishwar Kotis can return

http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_1/26_festival_at_adhars.htm

From Gospels of Ramakrishna Paramhans

> Yoga and the six centres
>
> MASTER: "Yoga is not possible if the mind dwells on 'woman and gold'.
>   The mind of a worldly man generally moves among the three lower
>   centres: those at the navel, at the sexual organ, and at the organ of
>   evacuation. After great effort and spiritual practice the Kundalini is
>   awakened. According to the yogis there are three nerves in the spinal
>   column: Ida, Pingala, and Sushumna. Along the Sushumna are six
>   lotuses, or centres, the lowest being known as the Muladhara. Then
>   come successively Svadhisthana, Manipura, Anāhata, Visuddha, and Ājnā.
>   These are the six centres. The Kundalini, when awakened, passes
>   through the lower centres and comes to the Anāhata, which is at the
>   heart. It stays there. At that time the mind of the aspirant is
>   withdrawn from the three lower centres. He feels the awakening of
>   Divine Consciousness and sees Light. In mute wonder he sees that
>   radiance and cries out: 'What is this? What is this?'
>
> "After passing through the six centres, the Kundalini reaches the
>   thousand petalled lotus known as the Sahasrara, and the aspirant goes
>   into samādhi.
>
> "According to the Vedas these centres are called 'bhumi', 'planes'.
>   There are seven such planes. The centre at the heart corresponds to
>   the fourth plane of the Vedas. According to the Tantra there is in
>   this centre a lotus called Anāhata, with twelve petals.
>
> "The centre known as Visuddha is the fifth plane. This centre is at
>   the throat and has a lotus with sixteen petals. When the Kundalini
>   reaches this plane, the devotee longs to talk and hear only about God.
>   Conversation on worldly subjects, on 'woman and gold', causes him
>   great pain. He leaves a place where people talk of these matters.
>
> "Then comes the sixth plane, corresponding to the centre known as
>   Ājnā. This centre is located between the eyebrows and it has a lotus
>   with two petals. When the Kundalini reaches it, the aspirant sees the
>   form of God. But still there remains a slight barrier between the
>   devotee and God. It is like a light inside a lantern. You may think
>   you have touched the light, but in reality you cannot because of the
>   barrier of glass.
>
> "And last of all is the seventh plane, which, according to Tantra, is
>   the centre of the thousand-petalled lotus. When the Kundalini arrives
>   there, the aspirant goes into samādhi. In that lotus dwells
>   Satchidananda Shiva, the Absolute. There Kundalini, the awakened
>   Power, unites with Shiva. This is known as the union of Shiva and
>   Śakti.
>
> The state of samādhi
>
> **"When the Kundalini rises to the Sahasrara and the mind goes into
>   samādhi, the aspirant loses all consciousness of the outer world. He
>   can no longer retain his physical body. If milk is poured into his
>   mouth, it runs out again. In that state the life-breath lingers for
>   twenty-one days and then passes out. Entering the 'black waters' of
>   the ocean, the ship never comes back. But the Isvarakotis, such as the
>   Incarnations of God, can come down from this state of samādhi. They
>   can descend from this exalted state because they like to live in the
>   company of devotees and enjoy the love of God. God retains in them the
>   'ego of Knowledge' or the 'ego of Devotion' so that they may teach
>   men.** Their minds move between the sixth and the seventh planes. They
>   run a boat-race back and forth, as it were, between these two planes

Comment: Good Answer. I was about to post on Isvarakotis as well. You should probably remove most of the non bold parts as it's not related to question.

Comment: well, Z cant be reached without starting from A. Seven Chakras or 7 days of week or 7 Grahas+Rahu/Ketu is what all of creation lives and their horoscope lives in.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for taking birth even the Jeeva is eligible for Moksha?
I'm asking this question for normal human beings, not for the avatar as Krishna, Rama etc.,

If possible, then show an example of such human being, if exists.

Yes Great example come to my mind is Guru Raghavendra.. He was mukthi yogya ( atma sakshathkara and prathkasha of lord vishu) is necessary both happened when he was prahlad..

1. Prahlad
2. Bhalika
3. Vyasa thirtha
4. Raghavendra Thirtha (still residing living in his brindhavana granting valid wishes of bhaktha)

According Great madhva pantha (Religion of hanuman) mukthi yogya is the one who had got atmasakshathkara and lord darsha.

But how people identify those ordinary people. Easy there fame is wide spread, they live normal life, they are not after anything material only lords feet.

Another example

1. KanakaDasa (Atmasakshath kara by guru kripa like (purandaradasa, vyasa thirtha and vadiraja) and Lord krishna Darshan..